# oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unknown Authentication, Encryption or Data Integrity algorithm

Tags: java, database, oracle, encryption, jdbc

I am getting issue while having a jdbc connection with `crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA256` getting below error.

```
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unknown Authentication, Encryption or Data Integrity algorithm
```

It is working fine with SHA1. Mentioned are the JVM args I am using

```
        -Doracle.net.encryption_client=REQUIRED
        -Doracle.net.encryption_types_client=AES256
        -Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED
        -Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA256 -- (failing)
        -Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA1 --> working
```

Can anyone help us here for DB side to understand why it is complaining only for SH256?

I checked SQL.NET ORA file and below are the server side setting.

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT = (SHA256,SHA1)
```

Comment: what is the jdbc driver version?

Comment: You need to upgrade your driver.

Comment: I am using below Oracle-jdbc 11.2.0.2.0 . What version are you suggesting ?